# How to count the characters in comments in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I was wondering if there is a way to count the characters in a comment in excel? I have to take these comments and put them into another application and was wondering if I could get a character count because the application only accepts 150 characters and I know some of the comments have more than that, but I don't want to sit there and count these comments out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do it via a formula but can do it with VBA

```
Dim com As Comment
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets(1)
For Each com In ws.Comments
    MsgBox Len(com.Text)
Next com
```

you can add a module and create a function as well

```
Function CountCommentCharacters(r As Range) As Integer
    CountCommentCharacters = Len(r.Comment.Text)
End Function
```